# Linux ubuntu terminal is one color, no syntax highlight

Tags: ubuntu, shell, terminal

So I have a trouble figuring out how to change everything back to normal in my terminal's text

Everything is gray, it supposed to show colors like its a directory or a file. Or show colors in color. But all of my terminal is this single color

[image: Gray terminal]

I tried methods from internet like changing the configuring file(.profile) but it didn't work

Note: if I change to another user, the syntax goes back to normal with su - USERNAME

Comment: Can you create a new user account and test whether it affects them?

Comment: It didn't affect the other user

Comment: Turn off "transparency" in the *Profile*.

Comment: It ... didn't work, I turned off the background transparency

Comment: Right click in the terminal window, select  Preferences, and then the tab Colours and then try various settings ...

Comment: You may want to try `ls --color=always`.

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- In the top tool bar, click on "Edit"-> "Open preferences"-> "Colors" tab.

Here is where you can control your color settings. I have "show bold text in bright colors" box checked.

Click on "Text color" it will open a color palette.